# Can I share business objects between UWP client and a WCF server?

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

Can I do a classic n-tier app with a UWP client and a WCF server, where a business objects are in a shared library (so I don't have to generate proxy classes as in Silverlight)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the general idea of portable class library would let the library be used in server and mobile apps. Caveats include need to be careful about dependencies, there is a fair amount of flux between "versions" of PCL-ness versus netStandard versions, and certain target platforms (like Xamarin) have their own specific narrowing to portability, but again, the basic answer is yes.

Comment: thanks. can I reuse non portable library? I want the app to run on win 10 only.

Comment: @BoppityBop If both server and client will only target Win 10, you probably don't need portable library. I've not experimented with this, most of my recent work targets .NET Core on Docker for services and Xamarin mobile for clients, so PCL or NET Standard library types for sharing code.

Comment: the only way I could find is PCL only. It seems a "regular" class library cannot be referenced by UWP project. not what I can find..